# Как сделать, чтобы телеграм бот отвечал только при обращении к нему?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Есть бот который отвечает на сообщения в групповом чате. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтоб он отвечал определённым образом (без разницы каким, пусть будет просто "привет") если пользователь обращается именно к нему? То есть когда пользователь свайпает влево сообщение от бота и отвечает на него (для pyTelegramBotAPI).
Заранее спасибо!

Спасибо Violet за код:

```
import config, telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None)
def handle_text_doc(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'OKAY!')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def messages(message):
    if message.text == "test":
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Done!')

#ЗАПУСК БОТА--------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала воспользуемся модулем [`logging`](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#logging), чтобы получить всю информацию о сообщении:

```
import logging

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

запустив бота и ответит на сообщение в группе, получим что-то вроде этого:

> 2022-01-14 20:36:18,129 (apihelper.py:155 PollingThread) DEBUG -
> TeleBot: "The server returned:
> 'b'{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":389456607,\n"message":{"message_id":203,"from":{"id":127*811,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"*","last_name":"Violet","username":"*_Violet","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":-100*680,"title":"test
> group","username":"dvttg","type":"supergroup"},"date":1642181777,"reply_to_message":{"message_id":199,"from":{"id":995*866,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"violet-it","username":"violet*"},"chat":{"id":-100*680,"title":"test
> group","username":"dvttg","type":"supergroup"},"date":1642181621,"text":"Hi"},"text":"\u044b"}}]}''"

здесь нас интересует только:

- `"reply_to_message":{` - признак что на сообщение ответили

После воспользуемся документацией https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#message-handlers и примером:

```
# Handles all messages for which the lambda returns True
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.document.mime_type == 'text/plain', content_types=['document'])
def handle_text_doc(message):
    pass
```

Т.к. мы знаем, что при ответе на сообщение в объекте будет присутствовать `reply_to_message`, тогда изменим пример следующим образом:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None)
def handle_text_doc(message):
    pass
```

т.е. это обработчик сообщений, который сработает если `message.reply_to_message` не пуст.

вместо `pass` используем `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')` и проверяем.

При необходимости меняем на `bot.reply_to(message, 'Привет')`

Comment: Круто! Действительно работает, спасибо! (добавил код)
Но получается, что обработчик будет срабатывает на любой ответ любого участника друг другу. 
В логе я нашел номер бота (?) (bot1981266498)

2022-01-19 21:13:39,4 (apihelper.py:84 WorkerThread2) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=post url=https://api.telegram.org/bot1981266498
:{TOKEN}/sendMessage params={'chat_id': '-524797982', 'text': 'OKEY!', 'reply_to_message_id': 1508} files=None"
2022-01-19 21:13:39,432 (util.py:79 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Received task"

Можно как-то сделать, чтоб обработчик реагировал только на него?

Comment: добавьте в условие хэндлера ` and message.from_user.id == id бота` и проверьте, так же если ответ решает ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, отметьте его таковым это поможет другим пользователям.

Comment: @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None and message.from_user.id == 1981266498) 
Не работает. Видимо user id не подходит для id бота.